# how to put line and dots under a title with css

Tags: html, css

I want to put a line under a titlw with dots. like so: [image] How can I do that? I am beginner at CSS.  I tried to do it using before and after I could not achieve it though. Thanks in advance

Comment: This community is not a coding service. Please try and update your question with your attempts and then the experts will be ready to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help,

```css
.text-wrapper {
    max-width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}


.text-wrapper h2 {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.text-wrapper h2:after {
    width: 50px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #adadad;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 0;
}
.text-wrapper h2:before {
    width: 50px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background: #adadad;
    bottom: -4px;
    right: 0;
}

.dots {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ff9800;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
.dots-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-wrapper">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="dots-wrapper">
    <div class="dots"></div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```